# Создается слишком много сессий по сравнению с количеством реальными пользователями

Tags: сессия

Здравствуйте

Создается слишком много сессий по сравнению с количеством реальными пользователями.
За неделю создалось 325 тыс. сессии (файлики), реальных же пользователей было ~35-40 тыс.

Разница в десять раз.
Почему их так много? И как их можно уменьшить?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это все зависит от того, как вы создаете сессии. Скорее всего большинство сессий - неиспользуемые. Тут еще не совсем понятно что вы имеете в виду под session.

- Какой-то пользователь не может отдать куки, или еще что, и в итоге каждое его посещение создает новую сессию;
- Время жизни сессии маленький, в итоге пользователь создает сессии каждые N дней;
- Старые сессии не удаляются.

Варианты, которые вижу я:

- Очищать неиспользуемые сессии;
- Разобраться, почему, в каких ситуациях они размножаются.